# WPF MouseRightButtonUp Event won't fire

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling

The MouseRightButtonUp event will not fire when the user releases the mouse right button. The user clicks the mouse right button to begin drawing a rectangle, so when they lift up the right button it needs to stop drawing by setting a bool to false. The Mouse Move event then knows not to continue drawing the rectangle. The mouse right button down event fires fine but the mouse right button up event will not fire.

I am currently thinking it is because of the ZoomBorder class, but that does not use any right button events I am almost certain. When I use a break point to see if mouse right button click fires it does sometimes recognize that it fires, but it does so at seemingly random times when right mouse button is up, but its not a time delay. if the mouse right button is up and you move it a bunch the event will sometimes fire.

I have tried moving the event into the canvases, the ZoomBorder, and the grid.

XAML:

```
<Grid Grid.Column="2" MinWidth="700">
   <ScrollViewer>
       <paz:ZoomBorder Name="zoomBorder" Stretch="None" ZoomSpeed="1.1" 
                       Background="White" ClipToBounds="True" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

                       <Canvas Name="gridCanvasOverImage">
                            <Canvas Name="canvasOverImage">
                                <Image x:Name="loadedImage"
                                       Stretch="Uniform"                                                                               
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                       VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                       MouseRightButtonDown=
                                            "LoadedImage_MouseRightButtonDown"
                                       MouseRightButtonUp=
                                            "LoadedImage_MouseRightButtonUp"
                                       MouseMove="LoadedImage_MouseMove"/>

                                 <Rectangle x:Name="rectangleOverImage"
                                             Stroke="SkyBlue"/>
                            </Canvas>
                         </Canvas>
          </paz:ZoomBorder>
     </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Code behind in C#:

```
// <Simplified C#>
//* Mouse button up
private void LoadedImage_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            drawRect = true; // Starts drawing of rectangle  
        }

//* Mouse Button Down
private void LoadedImage_MouseRightButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            drawRect = false;
        }

//* Drawing Rectangle
 private void LoadedImage_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (drawRect) // If the right mouse button is down
            {
                // Do Stuff
            }
        }
// </Simplified C#>
```

When the user lifts up the right mouse button it sets the drawing variable bool to false, which should stop the program from doing stuff in LoadedImage_MouseOver, but it doesn't. Once the right button is clicked, it keeps drawing the rectangle even if you lift the mouse button up again.

Thanks for any answers, anything is appreciated.

Comment: Does the LoadedImage_MouseMove continue to fire as you move the mouse or does it just fire initially?  If it is only firing initially then it wouldn't ever pick up drawRect after it's changed to false.

Comment: Most time the mouse events are handled by the framework before they reach your handler. You will be more successful when handling the [Preview Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/preview-events) (e.g. PreviewMouseRightButtonDown, PreviewMouseRightButtonUp).

Comment: Thank you everyone! It wouldn't work with preview events, but Catarina's solution worked perfectly. I don't know why, considering that the image is within the canvas and the click event is set on the image, but for some reason the canvas cannot be transparent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Canvas element need's to have background color and it can't be full transparent, because in this two cases all of the events won't be dispulted.

If you don't want to give it a color, set an almost transparent one, you wont even notice.
Example: `#02FFFFFF`

Comment: That fixed it, thank you! I greatly appreciate it, though I don't understand why that would change the way events fire. Do you, or anyone else, know why?

Comment: I don't know, but maybe because since it's transparent the area to be clicable is empty.